# Why is the index of an array a string in the below code?

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, indexing

```js
var arrayOfNumbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 78];
for(var index in arrayOfNumbers){
   console.log(index+1);
}
```

The output for this sample code is.
01
11
21
31
41
51
61

Why are these indexes of an array treated as a string in JavaScript?

Comment: Because those are string.Try `typeof index` it returns `"string"` type

Comment: keys of objects are always strings.

Comment: if you want add index with 1 then you can try this  console.log(parseInt(index)+1);
agree with @NinaScholz

Comment: A classic object has properties { 'foo' : 'hello' }, an array [ 'hello' ] is basically the same than { '0' : 'hello' }. Arrays are just objects where property names are indices, yet, it finally ends as a string.

Comment: Yep, and `for..in` are originally meant for object, so it is wise to return a string as objects's keys are always string.

Comment: @rohitwtbs i have posted a answer which can give you a expected out put.

Comment: The index is not a string, ‘index+1’ is. Cast index to an int and you should be fine

Comment: BTW `for...in` loop should be avoided to use with arrays. See this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500504/why-is-using-for-in-with-array-iteration-a-bad-idea).

Comment: @DeepakKamat Not just originally. They still are :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [MDN for...in](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in?#Array_iteration_and_for...in)

> **Note:** for...in should not be used to iterate over an Array where the index order is important.
>
> ... The for...in loop statement will return all enumerable properties,
> including those with non–integer names and those that are inherited.

When using *for...in*, the key is always a string and all it does is string concatenation.

You have an array, so better use [Array.foreach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) like so:

```js
var arrayOfNumbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 78];
arrayOfNumbers.forEach(function(item, index){
     console.log(index + 1); // Here the index is a number!
});
```

Comment: And that is because object's keys are always strings, no matter if it is `{ 0: "some value" }` or `'0': "value value.."`

Comment: yeah i checked with typeof and it is a string.My query is like in other languages such as JAVA it would be a integer but why these index are string in javascript?

Comment: @rohitwtbs cause with using `for in ` it treats your array as an object and object keys are always strings.

Comment: @caramba got it .

Answer (score 0):

A key is a string, because it is an object. In JavaScript there is *Object* and that's why its keys are in string.

You can achieve this by converting the string into *int* or add the prefix `+`.

```
var arrayOfNumbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 78];
for(var index in arrayOfNumbers) {
  var v = parseInt(index) + 1;
  console.log(v);
}
```

With a prefix

```js
var arrayOfNumbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 78];
for(var index in arrayOfNumbers) {
  var v = parseInt(index) + 1;
  console.log(v);
}
```

```
 var arrayOfNumbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 78];
 for(var index in arrayOfNumbers){
    var v = +index + 1;
     console.log(v);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Don’t use "for in" for an array. 'for in' is meant for traversing the object. When you try it with an array, it looks like this:

```
arr = {
    "0": 1,
    "1": 2,
    "2": 3,
    "3": 4,
    "4": 5,
    "5": 6,
    "6": 78
}
```

I hope you are looking for this:

```
var arrayOfNumbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 78];
for(var index=0; index<arrayOfNumbers.length; index++) {
     console.log(index+1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Reference: [MDN FOR..IN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in)

The *for...in* statement iterates over the enumerable properties of an object. For each distinct property, statements can be executed.

```js
var string1 = "";
var object1 = {a: 1, b: 2, c: 3};

for (var property1 in object1) {
  string1 = string1 + object1[property1];
}

console.log(string1);
```

In your case the indexes are referred to as object keys, which is a t string or a key string : `{ foo : 'something in universe'}`

Have a look here, if you want the key's value:

```js
var arrayOfNumbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 78];
for(var index in arrayOfNumbers) {
    console.log(arrayOfNumbers[index+1]);
}
console.log(arrayOfNumbers)
```

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the comments and some answers, a *for in* loop is intended for object iterations, and in JavaScript arrays are objects as well. So the keys will be of type string.

However, for your intended result, you could use something like this:

```
var arrayOfNumbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 78];
arrayOfNumbers.forEach(function(num)
{
    console.log(num+1);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

From *[for...in](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in)* (MDN):

> The for...in statement iterates over the enumerable properties of an object.

So the value of `index` in your code will always return the names of those properties. In an array, those are the names of the indexes.

Also, a `String` plus a `Number` equals a `String` which is what is printed in the `console`.